# Intercept POST of a form in CefSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I am bulding a WinForms application (VS2019, .NET 4.7.2) that wants to use `CefSharp` as its main UI (Cef 79.1.36+g90301bd+chromium-79.0.3945.130).

I have a simple form loaded from a local html file called `form.html`, where the relevant section (omitting most of the HTML boilerplate) looks like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="Place" placeholder="Place" /><br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The form file is loaded via a custom scheme:

```
settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme
{
    SchemeName = "folder",
    DomainName = "local",
    SchemeHandlerFactory = new FolderSchemeHandlerFactory(                    
    rootFolder: $@"{Application.StartupPath}\wwwroot",
    hostName: "local", 
    defaultPage: "index.html")
});
```

The code that actually loads it is in `Form1.cs` and looks like this:

```
browser.Load("folder://local/form.html");
```

The form loads fine and is displayed as expected.

Now, when the user presses the `Submit` button, I want to intercept the submission and handle the submitted data (the values entered for `Name` and `Place` in this case) in my C# code. I don't want the form to actually submit to any web server - I just need to be able to get to the form data and deal with it in my C#/WinForms code.

I am not sure how to do that. Right now, after the `Submit` button is clicked, the form gets cleared (presumably reloaded from the same url), but I don't know where the submitted data went. Would appreciate any clues.

Comment: `FolderSchemeHandlerFactory` is for serving static content. What do you need to do with the post data? What sort of response to the post request will you be providing?

Comment: @amaitland I will process the posted data in C#. In response, a new page is going to be loaded depending on the values in the posted form. There are no network communications involved whatsoever.

Comment: The easiest option is to implement your own scheme handler factory,  you can access post data via the request. Look at the FolderSchemeHandlerFactory source and use that as a starting point.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#scheme-handler

Comment: @amaitland Thank you! Exactly the clue I needed.